# Extract xml tag name into xml attribute value

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

The **sample xml** file is shown below

```
<a>
<apple color="red"/>
</a>
```

What should I write in XSLT so that i can get the **sample output** below ?

```
<AAA>
<BB bbb="#apple"/> <!-- if possible make it auto close -->
</AAA>
```

Comment: i not sure how to extract it, was thinking about to hard code it 
eg:
    `<AAA>
    <BB> **hard code here** </BB>
    <AAA>`

Comment: You may want to have a look at a more generic, completely parameterized solution. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`name()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-name) or [`local-name()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-local-name) functions:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/a">
    <AAA>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </AAA>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <BB bbb="{concat('#', name())}"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thanks it works perfectly ~ just because of the 
`{name()}` function ~ thanks a lot

Comment: @KirillPolishchuk: The result of your transformation is *different* from the OP's wanted result. Please, check and correct. Also, I believe that my generic solution might be interesting to have a look at, as it is completely parameterized vs the hardcoded values in this answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Here is a generic solution, that accept the name replacements to be made as parameters**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pReps">
  <e oldName="a" newName="AAA"/>
  <e oldName="apple" newName="BB"/>
  <a oldName="color" newName="bbb"/>
 </xsl:param>

 <xsl:variable name="vReps" select=
     "document('')/*/xsl:param[@name='pReps']"/>

 <xsl:template match="*">
     <xsl:element name=
     "{$vReps/e[@oldName = name(current())]/@newName}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
     </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="@*">
  <xsl:attribute name=
  "{$vReps/a[@oldName = name(current())]/@newName}">
   <xsl:value-of select="concat('#', name(..))"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<a>
    <apple color="red"/>
</a>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<AAA>
   <BB bbb="#apple"/>
</AAA>
```